# How can I prevent keyboard autocompletion in MobileSafari/UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, safari, uiwebview, mobile-safari

I'm implementing my own autocompletion on an <input> field inside a UIWebView, and the built-in keyboard autocompletion interferes with the user experience. Is there a way to use HTML or Javascript to signal to iOS that it shouldn't try to autocomplete?

Comment: how did you achieve `autocompletion` functionality with `UIWebView` ? I'm trying to implement the same in one of my app, Can you please share?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In my comments I mentioned using the html attribute `autocomplete` but I tested it, and it doesn't address your issue. However, there is an attribute specific to Mobile Safari which may help. You could try turning off **autocorrect** like so:

```
<input type="text" id="your-field" autocorrect="off" />
```

Comment: I should have guessed it would be that simple. Thanks!