# iOS 8 - UIWebView Keyboard - Previous/Next/Done Accessory Bar - How can I remove the toolbar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, uikeyboard

In my app, I have a hacked method to remove the "Previous/Next/Done Accessory Toolbar" on iOS7. My app is exported for iOS7, and of course runs on iOS8 - but I'm using older SDK.

When I run my app on iOS7 the bar is removed completely, and all I have is the keyboard - Awesome!

When I run my app on iOS8 the bar is back AND it has predictive text - it's horrible - I don't need ANY of these stupid bars in my app, it's just taking up space.

Is there a way to remove the toolbars from the UIKeyBoard within a UIWebView in iOS8 just like there was for iOS7, or am I going to just have to say "f it", and undo my hacks and just deal with the annoying extra toolbars that UIWebView thinks I want?

(This is why I dislike hybrid apps, but the code is already finished, and I cannot afford to switch to native, haha.)

Comment: try change the keyboardType. Maybe some it´s good for you. By example: yourTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;

Comment: keyboardtype to email, means i get a tiny space bar, and auto correct is disabled. this also keeps the previous/done/next bar - this will not help me in my situation.

Comment: Is this link any help? 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461101/how-can-i-prevent-keyboard-autocompletion-in-mobilesafari-uiwebview][1]

Comment: No, I don't mind auto completion, i DO mind predictive text bar, which is the new iOS8 bar that sits on top of the keyboard and shows 3 predicted words of what you are trying to type next - this has NOTHING to do with autocompletion which suggests words in the actual input text area via a small bubble.

Comment: I found the solution for iOS 8. You can check it here: [ iOS 8 - Remove Previous/Next/Done UIKeyboard Toolbar inside a UIWebView][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022089/remove-next-previous-buttons-inputaccessoryview-for-custom-keyboard-in-ios8

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://gist.github.com/bjhomer/2048571) , it works like a charm and it is much cleaner than the other solutions. It's hacking with the inputAccessoryView for UIWebBrowserView (inner UIWebView).

Good luck with coding!

Comment: broken link, please fix or remove your answer

Comment: This is the link, seems to me still alive: https://gist.github.com/bjhomer/2048571